# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'post') at AxiosServices.post (AxiosServices.js:7:1)

Tags: reactjs

I Am working on React + web 6.0 + sql server full stack app and creating post api method..

everything is work fine except below error.

[Console error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9wyL.jpg)

could you please help solve

[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGYnA.jpg)

[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ah8Z5.jpg)

error

[Images here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bpz09.jpg)

Comment: Probably accessing axios in you component, can you please share the code of the component?

Comment: Hi Naveen thanks ur msg.. could pls give solution i added code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using react no need to require axios like this with default property just do:

```js
import axios from "axios"

axios.post(url, {options})
```

Of course after installing it `npm i axios`

Comment: Ok 18jad. Thanks yo